# Calculating the difference between two two-digit years

Tags: r, difference

Is there any easy way in R to calculate the difference between two columns of two-digit years (just years, no months/days as it's unnecessary here) in order to produce a column of ages?

I've fairly new to this and have been playing with 'if' statements and algebra without success.

The data looks like this, but larger:

```
dat <- data.frame(year1=c("98","99","00","01","02"),
                  year2=c("03","04","05","06","07"))
```

Comment: You can convert the digit years to date type first and then perform difference. It would be great if you could share a sample of your data. Please share output of `dput(head(column.ages))` in the question description.

Comment: Is something like `dat <- data.frame(year1=c("98","99","00","01","02"), year2=c("03","04","05","06","07"))` what you're dealing with?

Comment: Exactly that but with 10000 in each column! @thelatemail

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strptime()` with the format `%y`:

```
dat <- data.frame(year1=c("98","99","00","01","02"),
    year2=c("03","04","05","06","07"),
    stringsAsFactors = F) # You might want to use this as a default!

dat$year1 <- strptime(dat$year1, format = "%y")
dat$year2 <- strptime(dat$year2, format = "%y")

as.vector(difftime(dat$year2,
    dat$year1,
    units = "days"))/365.242
4.999311 5.002163 4.999425 4.999425 4.999425
```

Answer (score 2):

Format to a date, format back to a number, take the difference:

```
do.call(`-`, lapply(dat[1:2], function(x) 
    as.numeric(format(as.Date(x, format="%y"), "%Y"))))
#[1] -5 -5 -5 -5 -5
```

This may hit cases where it doesn't work if you have old dates in the early 1900's. As per `?strptime`:

```
 ‘%y’ Year without century (00-99).  On input, values 00 to 68 are
      prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 - that is the behaviour
      specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do
      also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default
      century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.
```

Comment: Nice one, I like the use of ``-`` in `do.call` and of course the conversion of `%y` to `%Y`

Answer (score 0):

```
df$age <- ifelse(df$year2 < df$year1, df$year2 - df$year1 + 100, df$year2 -df$year1)
```

should work under the assumption `year2` is some kind of current year and `year1` is the year of birth and there are no people born before 1918.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(year1 = sample(18:99, 1000, replace = T), 
                 year2 = sample(1:99, 1000, replace = T))

> head(df)
  year1 year2
1    27    88
2    41    55
3    90    36
4    81    93
5    56    60
6    27    61

df$age <- ifelse(df$year2 < df$year1, df$year2 - df$year1 + 100, df$year2 -df$year1)

> head(df)
  year1 year2 age
1    73    88  15
2    50    17  67
3    47    41  94
4    54    43  89
5    36    82  46
6    62    85  23
```

With your data example:

```
dat <- data.frame(year1=c("98","99","00","01","02"),
                  year2=c("03","04","05","06","07"))

dat$age <- ifelse(as.numeric(as.character(dat$year2)) < as.numeric(as.character(dat$year1)), 
                  as.numeric(as.character(dat$year2)) - as.numeric(as.character(dat$year1)) + 100, 
                  as.numeric(as.character(dat$year2)) - as.numeric(as.character(dat$year1)))

> dat
  year1 year2 age
1    98    03   5
2    99    04   5
3    00    05   5
4    01    06   5
5    02    07   5
```

Answer (score 0):

one method is to use `as.Date` with a `dplyr` chain:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(year1 = as.Date(year1, format = "%y"), 
         year2 = as.Date(year2, format = "%y")) %>%
  mutate(age = year2 - year1)
```

which returns:

```
       year1      year2       age
1 1998-10-26 2003-10-26 1826 days
2 1999-10-26 2004-10-26 1827 days
3 2000-10-26 2005-10-26 1826 days
4 2001-10-26 2006-10-26 1826 days
5 2002-10-26 2007-10-26 1826 days
```

p.s. it assumes default day and month for both columns, but it assumes same value for both, so does not affect the difference calculation.